# How do I connect to multiple servers at the same time using gRPC in C++?

Tags: c++, grpc

I wanted to submit the same data to multiple servers at the same time using gRPC.

I looked at the greeterAsyn2 c++ example:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.8.x/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client2.cc

From the example: In order to create 1 channel you can just do this:

```
GreeterClient greeter(grpc::CreateChannel(
            "localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
```

As this would create the stub for the channel:

```
class GreeterClient {
  public:
    explicit GreeterClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel)
            : stub_(Greeter::NewStub(channel)) {}
}
```

And I would be able to submit data using

```
greeter.SayHello("hello world");
```

But what if I want to submit data to 2 different servers using 2 different channels?

If I would just add another GreeterClient object called greeter2:

```
GreeterClient greeter2(grpc::CreateChannel(
            "10.0.0.3:9008", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
```

I get a segmentation fault when trying to submit the data to the second server:

```
greeter2.SayHello("hello world");
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem now. Have you solved the seg fault on creating multiple connections to servers? It seems like a restriction on the client stub but not really clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing seems okay, I will need to see the stack trace to see what is going wrong.

Consider the channel as an abstract data pipe to a service and if you want to talk to multiple servers, just create multiple channels and send rpcs on them separately.